# Specifying lifetimes in nested iterators for flattening

Tags: iterator, rust, nested-loops, lifetime

I'm writing a function that should take a couple of vectors and produce their Cartesian product (all of their pair combinations) as a vector in row-major order. In other words, if I have

```
let x_coords = vec![1, 2, 3];
let y_coords = vec![4, 5, 6];
```

I want to produce

```
vec![ [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [2,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6] ]
```

This seemed like a perfect job for `.flat_map()`:

```
fn main() {
    let x_coords = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let y_coords = vec![4, 5, 6];

    let coord_vec: Vec<[isize; 2]> =
        x_coords.iter().map(|&x_coord| {
            y_coords.iter().map(|&y_coord| {
                [x_coord, y_coord]
            })
        }).flat_map(|s| s).collect();

    // Expecting to get: vec![ [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [2,4], [2,5], [2,6], [3,4], [3,5], [3,6] ]
    println!("{:?}", &coord_vec);
}
```

But this doesn't work, because `&x_coord` doesn't live long enough. According to the compiler, it ends up inside the `y_coords` map and then never makes it back out.

I tried using `.clone()` and `move` in the closures, but got a strangely long and unclear lecture by the compiler in the form of multiple `Note:` lines.

Am I just completely off base with `flat_map`, or can this be saved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

You were really close! This works:

```
let coord_vec: Vec<_> = x_coords.iter()
    .flat_map(|&x_coord| {
        y_coords.iter().map(move |&y_coord| {
        //                  ^^^^
            [x_coord, y_coord]
        })
    })
    .collect();
```

The only thing I added is the `move` keyword in front of the inner closure. Why? Let's try to understand what the compiler is thinking below!

A few notes, though:

- I renamed `map` to `flat_map` and removed the second `flat_map` call... You made your life more complicated than it has to be ;-)
- I omitted part of the type annotation of `coord_vec`, because it's not necessary

### Explanation

The type `x_coord` is `i32` (or any other integer). Not a reference or anything but the value directly. This means that `x_coord` is owned by the enclosing function, which happens to be a closure, specifically the "outer" closure, that you pass to `flat_map`. Thus `x_coord` lives just inside the closure, not longer. That's what the compiler is telling you. So far so good.

When you define the second closure (the "inner" one), you access the environment, specifically `x_coord`. The important question now is: how does a closure access its environment? It can do so with an immutable reference, with a mutable reference and by value. The Rust compiler determines what kind of access to the environment is needed and chooses the "least intrusive" option that works. Let's look at your code: the compiler figures out that the closure only needs to borrow the environment immutably (because `i32` is `Copy` and thus the closure can transform its `&i32` into a `i32` easily).

But in this case, the compiler's reasoning is wrong! The closure borrowing its environment leads to a limited lifetime. And in this case we need the closure to live for longer than it can, hence the error.

By adding `move`, we force the compiler to pass the environment to the closure by value (transferring ownership). This way the closure borrows nothing and can live forever (satisfies `'static`).

Comment: (I have the feeling my explanation is crap, but the text is getting long I can't think anymore. It's a tough topic and explaining it in one SO answer is a lot. Maybe I'll write a blog post about this... sorry for "not my best" :/)

Comment: *"The Rust compiler determines what kind of access to the environment is needed and chooses the "least intrusive" option that works."* A `move` closure always captures by value, a non-`move` closure always captures by reference (either with a mutable borrow if it's necessary or with an immutable borrow otherwise).

Comment: @FrancisGagné I thought that for a long time, too. But no, closures can take their env by value without `move`: [see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b1877b80394451899c894865c58fa58b&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: I guess I didn't really understand how `flat_map` is supposed to work either. This is a great answer!

Comment: @FrancisGagné yup; if any functions or methods in the closure take a closed-over variable by value, the compiler will know it needs to be `move`d in. However, if a method/function only needs it by reference, it will only go that far. `move` forces all the variables to be moved in.